# Pentaho step - Use SQL functions to add a column in data before dumping it int DB

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am fairly new to Pentaho, and while working on it, I have stumbled across a problem. Below is how my flow is:

1. Read input from a file. Let's say this has 5 columns.
2. Make some modifications to existing columns. (Filter, modify and all).
3. Add a new column, which will be equal to an SQL function of the current row data. Example, it can be sum(id, id+1)
4. Dump to the database.

Step 1,2, 4 are already in place and are working fine. It's Step 3 where I am stuck. I've tried to execute SQL, but that is only for Modifying DDL and doesn't return data. Table input needs data to be in a table already, which isn't the case with me.

I have a workaround, that I can enter all rows in DB, and then fire an update query, but I was hoping if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can add formula step and in the formula column, you can specify what you want to achieve. For example, your other column+1 and save it in a new field or also replace the existing field value

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do want to do something similar, however, the value that I want is an SQL function on my fields. Like SUM(COLUMN). Can I use formula for the same?

Comment: If you want to read from the database, formula step can't be used. But only on columns that are already available in the stream. What is your exact use case?